# what will happen if we add lithium cobalt oxide into water?is it true that molecule will break and lithium will make LiOH and CoO2?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aqueous-solution

I have tried to dissolve powder coated on cathode of lithium ion batteries.

Comment: Review the guide [How to ask](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Asking FAQs](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/asking) to prevent clarification requests, objections,  downvoting or closure.

Comment: There is no molecule of lithium cobalt oxide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no molecule of lithium cobalt oxide. There are negatively charged layers of $\ce{CoO2}$ intercalated with positive lithium ions.

$\ce{LiCoO2}$ and $\ce{CoO2}$ are extreme and unstable states of the general composition $\ce{Li_xCoO2}$. $\ce{LiCoO2}$ tends to form separate $\ce{Li2O}$ and $\ce{Co2O3}$. $\ce{CoO2}$ tends to release $\ce{O2}$, forming $\ce{Co2O3}$. These states are avoided by the cell under-/overcharge control.

$\ce{Li_xCoO2}$ can be written as $\ce{Li_xCo^{III}_xCo^{IV}_{(1-x)}O2}$.

Reaction with water gradually leads to respective hydroxid / hydrated oxide and oxygen.

$$\ce{4 Li_xCo^{III}_xCo^{IV}_{(1-x)}O2 + $(2+2x)$ H2O -> 4x LiOH + 4 CoO(OH) + $(1-x)$ O2}$$

Comment: Related discussion: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/134739/17368